# Filter date range from object with date as key in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the AlphaVantage API (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#daily) to get daily stock data. Unfortunately the API does not offer the option to get only data for a specific date range. It returns always all data from the last 20 years. The hash it returns contains the date as a key:

```
 "2016-12-08": {
        "1. open": "61.3000",
        "2. high": "61.5800",
        "3. low": "60.8400",
        "4. close": "61.0100",
        "5. volume": "21220753"
    },
    "2016-12-07": {
        "1. open": "60.0100",
        "2. high": "61.3800",
        "3. low": "59.8000",
        "4. close": "61.3700",
        "5. volume": "30808969"
    },
    "2016-12-06": {
        "1. open": "60.4300",
        "2. high": "60.4600",
        "3. low": "59.8000",
        "4. close": "59.9500",
        "5. volume": "19907035"
    },
```

How can I select only the entries for a give time range, eg. 2016-12-01 until 2016-12-10? I understand that I always will get the full data and will have do to the filtering on the returned hash.

Comment: So what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select`, like this:

```
response = {
  "2016-12-08": {
    "1. open": "61.3000",
    "2. high": "61.5800",
    "3. low": "60.8400",
    "4. close": "61.0100",
    "5. volume": "21220753"
  },
  "2016-12-07": {
    "1. open": "60.0100",
    "2. high": "61.3800",
    "3. low": "59.8000",
    "4. close": "61.3700",
    "5. volume": "30808969"
  },
  "2016-12-06": {
    "1. open": "60.4300",
    "2. high": "60.4600",
    "3. low": "59.8000",
    "4. close": "59.9500",
    "5. volume": "19907035"
  }
}

start_date = Date.new(2016, 12, 6)
end_date   = Date.new(2016, 12, 7)

response.select { |k, _| Date.parse(k.to_s) >= start_date && Date.parse(k.to_s) <= end_date }
#=> {
#    :"2016-12-07"=>{:"1. open"=>"60.0100", :"2. high"=>"61.3800", :"3. low"=>"59.8000", :"4. close"=>"61.3700", :"5. volume"=>"30808969"},
#    :"2016-12-06"=>{:"1. open"=>"60.4300", :"2. high"=>"60.4600", :"3. low"=>"59.8000", :"4. close"=>"59.9500", :"5. volume"=>"19907035"}
#   }
```

Comment: `response` is not a valid ruby hash so you need to parse it first

Comment: @MartinZinovsky I was missing a closing `}`; now its valid. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you already have hash, you can try use select:

```
hash.select { |k, _| Date.parse(k) < Date.parse("2016-12-10") && Date.parse(k) > Date.parse("2016-12-01")}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be using [`Hash#select`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/select) and a range:

```
def filter_dates(hash, first, last)
  range = Date.parse(first)..Date.parse(last)
  hash.select { |k, _| range.include?(Date.parse(k)) }
end
```